# Automatic data binding

Tags: java, android, user-interface, data-binding

I implemented data binding in a simple shopping app I made. Whenever I add an item to the cart, a `RelativeLayout` and two `TextView`s inside it have their values updated (especifically color and background). You might get a better idea on what I'm doing if I show you this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/shopping_cart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@{shoppingCart.isActive ? @color/lightBlue : @color/grey }"
        android:padding="13dp"
        android:onClick="buy">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cart_state"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{shoppingCart.state}"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cart_total"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(shoppingCart.totalPrice)}"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/cart_state"
            android:gravity="end"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

This actually works pretty well!

**But there's an issue:**

If I want to see the changes take place, I must start a new activity, and go back to the 'original' activity (like if I had to refresh the activity to see the data binding work its magic).

However, I'd really prefer if I could see the changes take place immediately, without having to refresh or reopen the activity.

I.e., how can I make the changes applied by data binding to be reflected instantly in the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to notify the view to update the binding when you update the value.

You can make your `ShoppingCart` class extends BaseObservable for the notifying ability.

Take a look at the example in the [document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability) below

```
class User : BaseObservable() {

@get:Bindable
var firstName: String = ""
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName)
    }

@get:Bindable
var lastName: String = ""
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.lastName)
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it, I had never really worked with Observables previously. I took a look at the documentation, but for some reason I had skipped that part entirely. Thank you very much!